# Install-Package System.Numerics.Vectors -Version 4.5.0 command does not work

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I've been suffering with the installation of the package
mentioned in the title in Visual Studio 2019.

My goal is to succesfully develop a Xamarin Android application.

I've tried NuGet Package Manager and even the associated consol.
However I do not progress regarding the issue.

I receive the following error message: Error NU1101 Unable to find package System.Numerics.Vectors. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

Does anyone know how to resolve the error?

Comment: "does not work" is a useless description of the problem.  Do you get an error message or exception?

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: this seems like a pretty clear message: "No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages".  Why is it searching "Offline Packages"?  Have you checked your nuget sources?